# Careers "add an answer" link is gone after clicking

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When you click the "add an answer" link under "Top Answers", the link is replaced by a widget to add answers. When you click "close", the widget fades out but the "add an answer" link doesn't come back.

#### Before

[image: Before screenshot]

#### After

[image: After screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be good to go now.  Thanks for the report!